# Data on 2nd page showing data of 1st page in gridview with paging applied

Tags: c#, gridview, pagination

What to do if paging is applied on gridview.? If I try to show data of each row, on 2nd page , it shows me data of 1st page on the 2nd page of grid as well. What to do?

my code is:-
protected void gvbind()
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Reference.ReferenceID,Reference.Name,Reference.JobTitle,Reference.Organization,Reference.Phone,Reference.Email,Reference.City, Reference.StateProvince, Reference.Country, Reference.ReferenceType from Reference JOIN JResume ON Reference.ResumeID= JResume.ResumeID JOIN JUser ON UserID=JResume.ResumeID AND JUser.Email=@Email", conn1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value = Session["Login"].ToString();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);
    SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();


    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        grid1.DataSource = ds;

        grid1.DataBind();
        int CountRowsPerPage = grid1.Rows.Count; // as paging is applied so count number of rows per page to display
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grid1.Rows)
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
               // int RowIndex = grid1.PageIndex * grid1.PageSize + row.RowIndex;

                Label ReferenceLabel = (Label)grid1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ReferenceLabel") as Label;
                if (!(ReferenceLabel == null))
                {
                    ReferenceLabel.Text = "";
                    ReferenceLabel.Text = dr["JobTitle"].ToString() + " in " + dr["Organization"].ToString() + "<br/> " + dr["City"].ToString();

                    ReferenceLabel.Text += " , " + dr["Country"].ToString();
                    ReferenceLabel.Text += " <br/> " + dr["Phone"].ToString() + "<br/>" + dr["Email"].ToString();

                }
            }
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Nobody answered my question as always on this website. So after whole hardwork on my own, i'm going to answer myself the first time.

protected void grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label ReferenceLabel = (Label)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ReferenceLabel");

```
        if (ReferenceLabel != null)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
            {
                ReferenceLabel.Text = "";
                ReferenceLabel.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["JobTitle"].ToString() + " in " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["Organization"].ToString() + "<br/> " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["City"].ToString();

                ReferenceLabel.Text += " , " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["Country"].ToString();
                ReferenceLabel.Text += " <br/> " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["Phone"].ToString() + "<br/>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["Email"].ToString();
            }

        }

    }
}
```